# Does the magnitude of your grip on a pullup bar affect how hard or easy it is to do pullups

Tags: pull-ups, chin-ups, grip-strength, grip

I do pullups and chinups in my garage all the time. I do them on a metal beam that runs across the ceiling and helps hold up the second floor. It is an I beam, so my grip isn't ever really ideal, but I don't have a problem with it.

If I were to use a more conventional bar, would the amount of reps I can do increase?

Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, having a better grip makes pull-ups a lot easier, and increases the number you can do, often dramatically.

Comment: On the flip side of things, doing the pull-ups with an inadequate grip like on an I-beam can improve your hand strength, so it's not all bad.

Answer (score 2):

Gripping tight would also create tension in your body, which helps for exciting the CNS. Here is a link: http://www.rdlfitness.com/use-a-tight-grip/

It would get your grip stronger, it would increase your pull-up power.